# Get number of contacts in address book with iOS 9

Tags: ios, ios9

Until iOS 8, you could use the `AddressBook` framework and `ABAddressBookGetPersonCount` to get the number of contacts in the address book.

With iOS 9, `AddressBook` is deprecated in favor of `Contacts`. However in the [documentation for `CNContactStore`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/contacts/cncontactstore) I can't find any mention of a similar method to get the total number of contacts in the address book.

Is my only option to iterate through all contacts just to count them?

Comment: I guess they must have changed it to something like they did for String as - string.length to string.characters.count. I hope you can find in that way.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, unfortunately could not find anything similar. It's probably a completely different paradigm.